# JSF h:inputText's keeps old data after a4j:commandButton submit

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

Ok, I have something like this:

```
<a4j:form ignoreDupResponses="true">
    <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax" immediate="true" id="panelId">
        <rich:tab label="Name" name="NAME" action="#{bean.clearData()}">
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.value1}" required="true"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{bean.value2}" required="true"/>
            <rich:messages/>
            <a4j:commandButton action="#{bean.someAction()}" value="OK"
                reRender="panelId" />
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab label="Name2" name="NAME2">
            <!-- Some content -->
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</a4j:form>
```

`bean.someAction()` is a function that saves in my DB `value1` and `value2`.
`bean.clearData()` is a function that clears `value1` and `value2` from by bean, or loads it if it is already saved in the DB.

Here is my problem... When I type `value1` some value, and then I leave `value2` blank, I will get some messages printed in `<rich:messages/>`.
Then I switch to the tab "Name2", and after that I return to the tab "Name1", the webpage will show the old value for any `<h:inputText/>`, since I executed `bean.clearData()` the values are empty in my bean and in they are not even in the conversation.

edit: my form retains the data and does not clear it, even when it is not inside the bean anymore.

All I can think of is the browser cache'ing the data, and I want to avoid the data to load when it is not saved in my DB. Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this?
I have tried autocomplete="off" in the h:inputText with no results.

PS: using FireFox 12.0

Comment: The problem description in your "Here is my problem.." paragraph is not clear.Pls rephrase it.Is the form retaining the value and not clearing it?

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM I edited it, but you nailed it, that is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

did you try a `reRender="panelId"` within your `<a4j:form>`?

Comment: I added it and it seems to work, but I find it ridiculous to reRender the form each time I switch tabs after a submit to avoid this problem which seems to be caused due to the browser's autocomplete. I know that if the user's don't like this, they could disable it, but some of them barely know how to turn on a PC

Answer (score 0):

in browser settings give clear history, cookies, cache, etc `automatically`.
I think then it will work.